# Isn't requiring a file before it's loaded by WordPress itself a symptom of bad code?

Tags: core

There's a lot of `if( !function_exists(... { require ABSPATH . '/file.php` in the industry. We didn't crash, the world still lives, yet I wonder - **isn't this one of the worst things you can do in an event driven system like WordPress is?**

At first sight, you're just including classes / functions that do nothing by the require alone, ye? Wrong. If you need to `require` a file, you also plan on using a function. Inside that function, there could be `do_action` that should only fire once and at the right time, yet you're firing them here. What if a critical piece of code relies on that action to fire at a certain moment when a resource is available?

Then, shouldn't we have a lot of errors in the eco-system?

What am I misunderstanding here? To me, in theory, this seems like you open yourself to so many fatal errors doing this, yet we're all fine.

Comment: just requiring a function file doesn't necessarily mean you are firing the actions in it... the actions are (usually) still inside functions or classes so they are only triggered when called/instantiated.

Comment: "_isn't this one of the worst things you can do in an event driven system like WordPress is?_" - what does that have to do with PHP natively not supporting autoloading (for many years)? These `require` are necessary (pre-OOP PHP) so the compiler knows about your code.

Comment: @majick I specified that, of course, that is only a reference, but if you use a function which in turn has `do_action` inside of it, you're firing actions at a time when they shouldn't. That can't not be a problem.

Comment: @kero My issues isn't with PHP or `require` or `autoloading`. When you require a file, you just simply hold a reference to it. Inside that file, there's functions and classes (hopefully you don't have files that also do calls when included), my problem is, as I explained to majick as well, when you call a function from that file when it's too early, you're executing a `do_action` at a time when it's not supposed to happen.

Comment: **My quarrel is that if you execute an action, by proxy of using a function containing it, if something hooks into that said action, it will execute code at the wrong time.**

Comment: Plugins and themes use actions and filters all the time, only rarely does context become a real conflict problem requiring some kind of workaround. In any case that is the responsibility of the person adding the action/filter, it's not as though simply providing the actions/filters themselves is in itself a problem, on the contrary it makes being able to add/modify existing behaviour easier. If in the edge case of something being called out of order, then there is a procedural problem to be resolved and a workaround or refactoring may be needed.

Comment: @majick I believe the solution here is...well, for the person hooking into that action to simply handle the case where, if he relies on certain things...do something if they're not there. As simple as that. But this is treating the symptom, isn't it? The disease is that you have to use a function when it's not there for you, it means that whatever you're writing is **hooking way too early.**

Comment: that is possible yes, but doesn't cover all cases, for example /wp-admin functions or classes might need to be included when they otherwise would not be.available, or you need to calculate something early specifically to handle conditional loading.